# JSP page fails to load data when is returned from Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a problem with a JSP page. Here is how my page looks like, very simple.

```
@GetMapping("/showTable")
public ModelAndView checkCandidateStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("table");

    // get some data and send it to jsp
    model.addObject("tableData", tableRecords);
    return model;
}
```

If I am accessing this page from the menu (with click so also a GET request) everything works ok but if I am trying to return this page from other controllers:

```
@PostMapping("/editRow")
public String editRow(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //some code here
     return "table";
}
```

Here for the last endpoint when I return the same JSP page like above "table.jsp" the page loads only the static content without data, just plain HTML.

From what I understand there is returned just the JSP page and the endpoint **/showTable** is called so no data added. Is there a way to return a valid **table** view from my **/editRow** endpoint?

**Edit:** I can call directly the above endpoint but I am thinking that maybe there is a more elegant way to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you written any code on table.jap page to show data ? You have to use jstl tag in table.jsp to show data by including it like `<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

Comment: in `/editRow` endpoint you didn't set any data what I can see now. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ajinkya I have added jstl. user404 data is there. I have removed that part in order to be easier to read the code. As I said I click on the href that calls that endpoint works on (data is display as it should) but if I simply return "table" from other endpoint is displayed just the static html without data.

Comment: Can u please add the JSP page code here

Answer (score 0):

You have added data to the JSP using model in this code:

```
@GetMapping("/showTable")
public ModelAndView checkCandidateStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("table");

    // get some data and send it to jsp
    model.addObject("tableData", tableRecords);
    return model;
}
```

Similarly, you have to add model object to the JSP page like this:

```
@PostMapping("/editRow")
public String editRow(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //some code here
    // get some data and send it to jsp
     model.addObject("tableData", tableRecords);
     return "table";
}
```